# Supply xml element value in modify() method

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I know how to replace element value for the xml element in the modify() method. Here's the example

[TSQL Replace value in XML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195833/tsql-replace-value-in-xml-string)

My problem is a bit different. Taking example from above link...

```
UPDATE dbo.TFS_Feedback_New
    SET Details.modify('
        replace value of (/optional/educational/text())[1]
        with sql:variable("@updatedEducation")')
    WHERE feedbackID = @FBID
```

What I want to do is provide value for 'educational'. In other words I want to do something like this

```
UPDATE dbo.TFS_Feedback_New
SET Details.modify('
        replace value of (/optional/sql:variable("@name")/text())[1]
        with sql:variable("@value")')
WHERE feedbackID = @FBID
```

I'm getting the following error because of `sql:variable("@name")`

The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.

How can I pass both the name of the element to be updated and its value to my 
stored procedure and have it update the XML column?

Comment: Next time please provide a *stand-alone* scenario, at least a (reduced!) example of your XML, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to use variables as part of the `XPath`, but you can use a predicate:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
    <optional>
        <educational>SomeText</educational>
        <someOther>blah</someOther>
    </optional>
  </root>';
```

--The *straight* approach as you know it:

```
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/optional/educational/text())[1] with "yeah!"');

SELECT @xml;
```

--Now we use a variable to find the first node below `<optional>`, which name is as given:

```
DECLARE @ElementName VARCHAR(100)='educational';

SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/optional/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@ElementName")]/text())[1] with "yeah again!"');

SELECT @xml;
```

Try it out...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. But now I have subtle issue. I want to replace if node exists and if it doesn't I want to insert. So I know how to insert, but when I want to do a check, will this work .exist('sql:variable("@token") where @token 'is/root/optional/educational'. Asking because it is not detecting

Comment: @griftopia Regrettfully that's not a *subtle issue*... There is no *one-liner-approach* for this. In most cases people use some `IF`-approach: Check for the existance and switch into the appropriate code. Quite often people insert the node **before** the one you want to change in any case and remove the second one...

Comment: @griftopia Sorry, did not read your comment carefully enough (or you've edited it later ,-)  ), No, you cannot insert an `Xpath` as variable into `.exist()`. One more trick was to create the whole statement dynamically and use `EXEC` for the execution. This allows to build the `Xpath` out of variables and still execute a statement with a literal `Xpath`...

Comment: First, I cannot seem to include multiple line in comments or would have made my question clearer. Second, yes, I see what you are saying with EXEC, but would like to avoid EXEC or sp_executesql if possible. Thanks again.